# SQL Server query - interval values maximizing a SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, max

I need an SQL Server query that returns two values (t1 and t2) corresponding to ONE decimal field so that they define an interval for which a certain SUM gets maximized. The SUM is performed over successful records (field result > 0) and unsuccessful ones (field result < 0). In other words: which is the value segment in which the net result is optimized?
Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

MORE INFO

-table "operations" is the target SQL table, these queries would involve the relevant fields:
`SELECT t from operations where result > 0`

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS num from operations where result > 0`

-field "t" is a decimal value, I am searching for 2 values of "t", for example "t1=1.25" and "t2=2.6"

-field "result" is an integer value, could be > 0 (it wins, for example "15") or < 0 (it looses, for example "-10")

-The following query works ok in returning an interval for "t" (t1 and t2) arbitrarily determined as t > 1 and t < 1.5:
`SELECT DISTINCT (select MIN(t) from operations where t > 1) As t1,
(select MAX(t) from operations where t < 1.5) As t2
from operations`

OBJECTIVE:
-table "operations" has about 500 records, some of them are successful ("result" > 0) or unsuccessful ("result" < 0), "t" is a decimal field featuring several values, lets say between 1.2 and 5.8
-for simplifying purposes, lets say that we only have those 2 fields, "t" and "result" - What are the 2 values for t (t1 and t2) so that for t > t1 and t < t2 we get the optimum result (i.e. the difference between winners and losers is maximized)?

```
+------------+-------------+
| t          | result      |
+------------+-------------+
| 1.25       |          15 |
| 1.1        |         -12 |
| 3.8        |          10 |
+------------+-------------+
```

For this small recordset, the expected values for t would be t1=1.25 and t2=3.8, because in the interval 1.25 <= t <= 3.8 the resuts are maximized (total results=15+10=25). For example 1.1 <= t <= 1.25 would lead to total results=15-12=3, which is not the optimum.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, in the question as *text* tables.

Comment: Even with "MORE INFO", I still have no idea what you're asking.   Read this and try editing your question one more time:   https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I managed to add the table with a small recordset ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you get the top 2 ordered by result, and include a ROW_NUMBER.
Then based on the row_number you can know t1 and t2.

```
SELECT 
MAX(case when rn = 1 then t end) as t1, 
MAX(case when rn = 2 then t end) as t2, 
MAX(case when rn = 1 then result end) as result1, 
MAX(case when rn = 2 then result end) as result2,
SUM(result) as optimum
FROM
(
  SELECT result, t, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t) as rn
  FROM
  (
    SELECT TOP 2 result, t
    FROM operations
    WHERE t BETWEEN 1.00 AND 4.00
    ORDER BY result DESC
  ) q1
) q2;
```

**Result:**

```
t1      t2      result1 result2 optimum
1.25    3.80    15      10      25
```

Comment: Thanks LukStorms, but does your query consider the RESULTS as the SUM of all results for records where t1 <= t <= t2?

Comment: I now added an example limit on t in the q1 sub-query.